# Converting singleton to non singleton and use deep copy instead

Tags: c#, .net, deep-copy

My question is rather opposite to lot of other questions, I want to convert an old singleton class to non singleton, especially to parallelize we need separate copies. Also the Singleton class itself contains other singleton class reference.

Would be a good idea to convert it to a non singleton class and use a deep copy instead for places where we need exactly same object, so that both the purpose are served

Comment: Whether this is a good idea or not seems to depend on the concrete scenario. For example, I'm unclear on why you need separate instances in the first place. Are they being mutated concurrently?

Comment: Right the collection is modified by multiple threads concurrently, to explain the logic, we have a foreach loop, which provides an object for an iteration, which is removed from collection and collection is submitted to figure out the performance and we cannot have more than one object removed at a given point so need to replicate the collection in separate copies. In fact as I can see, though it is against the design, but singleton itself can be created in a unique object using serialization